# Substituir texto BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, django

Tenho o seguinte html:

```html
<p>Um acidente no cruzamento da rua ... </p>
<div id="marca"></div>
<p>Um acidente no cruzamento ......</p>
<div id="marca2"></div>
```

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
def text_view(self):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.text)
    try:
        marca1 = BeautifulSoup(self.get_images())
        soup.find("div", {"id": "marca"}).replaceWith(marca1)
    except:
        pass

    try:
        marca2 = BeautifulSoup(self.get_images())
        soup.find("div", {"id": "marca2"}).replaceWith(marca2)
    except:
        pass

    return soup
```

Mas ele só substitui o texto do primeiro div.
O que pode ser?

Comment: O que é `self.get_images`? O que ele retorna? E o segundo código (`findAll`)  está assim mesmo, com `id`? Repare que no seu código a `div` possui a **classe** `marca2`, e não o id. Ou foi só um erro na hora de fazer a pergunta?

Comment: esse self.get_images() retorna uma lista html de imagens. Corrigi o código. Após outras tentativas não consegui ainda ):

Comment: ok, e essa lista de imagens possui ids? Reparei que você está usando os mesmos valores (o retorno de `self.get_images()`) em dois lugares diferentes. Se houver ids repetidos, pode dar problema - ainda que eu não tenha certeza se isso ocorre já no próprio BeautifulSoup ou só mais pra frente quando for renderizar o HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455148/520779), quando você insere um objeto `BeautifulSoup` dentro de outro objeto `BeautifulSoup`, o `find` deixa de funcionar corretamente - ele para a busca antes da hora (é um bug na implementação do `find`). Um *workaround* seria fazer todas as buscas primeiro, e todas as substituições depois:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(self.text)

# Primeiro busca tudo
ponto1 = soup.find("div", {"id": "marca"})
ponto2 = soup.find("div", {"id": "marca2"})

# Depois substitui tudo
marca1 = BeautifulSoup(self.get_images())
marca2 = BeautifulSoup(self.get_images())

ponto1.replaceWith(marca1)
ponto2.replaceWith(marca2)
```

Outro - como citado em resposta à pergunta linkada - seria refazer o objeto `BeautifulSoup` antes de fazer o segundo `find`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(self.text)
try:
    marca1 = BeautifulSoup(self.get_images())
    soup.find("div", {"id": "marca"}).replaceWith(marca1)
except:
    pass

# Refaz o objeto
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.renderContents())

try:
    marca2 = BeautifulSoup(self.get_images())
    soup.find("div", {"id": "marca2"}).replaceWith(marca2)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Funcionou com que foi uma beleza